# Can Thiamine Pyrophosphate be Prepared from Thiamine Hydrochloride by chemical means?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, biochemistry

Is there a quick and easy way to prepare Thiamine Pyrophosphate in the lab (i.e. without using micro-organisms) starting by Thiamine Hydrochloride (by a simple displacement reaction maybe)?

Comment: Give some more details. Why do you need this?

Comment: Thiamine pyrophosphate is commercially available [e.g. here](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/GB/en/product/sigma/c8754) This [patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/WO2016079576A1/en) describes a preparation from thiamine hydrochloride.

Comment: Would you by any chance know how to increase the yield (7%) of Thiamine Pyrophosphate in the first step of the reaction?

Comment: Vary temperature and time if you are trying to improve the process, but as it is commercially available I would just buy it if it is for a one-off use..